# Grafana build from source error (undefined: server.Initialize + undefined: server.InitializeForCLI)

Tags: go, cygwin, grafana

I am trying to build grafana from source with golang version 1.20.1 in Windows 10. Unfortunately i get the following error via Cygwin:

```
$ go run build.go build
Version: 10.1.0, Linux Version: 10.1.0, Package Iteration: 1693484960pre
building binaries build
building grafana ./pkg/cmd/grafana
rm -r ./bin/windows-amd64/grafana.exe
rm -r ./bin/windows-amd64/grafana.exe.md5
go build -ldflags -w -X main.version=10.1.0-pre -X main.commit=unknown-dev -X ma
in.buildstamp=1693484962 -X main.buildBranch=main -buildmode=exe -o ./bin/window
s-amd64/grafana.exe ./pkg/cmd/grafana
# github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/cmd/grafana-server/commands
pkg\cmd\grafana-server\commands\cli.go:228:19: undefined: server.Initialize
# github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/commands
pkg\cmd\grafana-cli\commands\commands.go:53:24: undefined: server.InitializeForC
LI
exit status 1
exit status 1
```

I have recently found a post regarding the above problem

https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-building-from-source-error-undefined-server-initialize/54711/7

and thus following the above steps regarding gen command

```
gen -tags oss ./pkg/server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/runner
```

i get the following Cygwin output

```
$ gen -tags oss ./pkg/server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/runner
-bash: gen: command not found
```

and regarding make gen-go command, i get the following Cygwin output

```
$ make gen-go
make: *** No rule to make target `gen-go’. Stop.
```

For your own convenience in my GOPATH/bin, i have got the following two files (wire.exe, wire-v.0.5.0).

[image]

Any idea that could help me?

Regards